# Select highest and lowest article in a database, how?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate, min

A table that has different articles. The task is to select the article with the highest and the one with the lowest price plus their article number (primary key)

It seems like an easy `MAX`/`MIN` but it does not really work out that well..

```
SELECT ArtNr, MAX(Price) AS Most_expensive, MIN(Price) AS CHEAPEST FROM article;
```

It only showing me the article number of the cheapest article. 
How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share table/code, it's very difficult to answer without having it

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
SELECT ArtNr, MAX(Price), 'Most Expensive'
FROM article
GRoup By ArtNr
union all
SELECT ArtNr, MIN(Price), 'Cheapest'
FROM article
GRoup By ArtNr
```

Comment: This query would probably generate a syntax error, since `ArtNr`, which is not aggregated,  is not part of a `GROUP BY` clause...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ArtNr, 
        Price, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Price) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Price DESC) rn_desc
    FROM article
) x WHERE rn_asc = 1 OR rn_desc = 1
```

The subquery assigns a rank to each product, ordered by ascending or descending price. The outer query filters on top and bottom prices.

If you want to allow top and bottom ties, you can use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

---

In earlier versons of MySQL, you can use correlated subqueries with `NOT EXISTS` conditions, like:

```
SELECT ArtNr, Price 
FROM article a
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM article a1 WHERE a1.Price > a.price) 
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM article a2 WHERE a2.Price < a.price)
```

Comment: Welcome @Henri_99! If my answer properly responded to your question, please *accept it* by clicking the green check sign... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use IN

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/686a0f/3

```
select * 
from article a
where a.price in
(
   SELECT MAX(Price) 
   from article
   union 
   SELECT MIN(Price) 
   from article      
)
order by price;
```

It just don't have another column to indicate if the price is highest or lowest. It would still work though if it so happen that all prices are the same, meaning the cheapest and expensive are the same :)

```
CREATE TABLE article
    (`art` varchar(1), `price` int)
;

INSERT INTO article
    (`art`, `price`)
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('C', 1),
    ('D', 3),
    ('E', 4)
;
```

Output:

```
| art | price |
|-----|-------|
|   A |     1 |
|   C |     1 |
|   E |     4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have very good performance with an index on `price`:

```
select a.* 
from article a
where a.price = (select max(a2.price) from article a2) or
      a.price = (select min(a2.price) from article a2);
```

This will return duplicates.  If you want exactly two rows, regardless of duplicates:

```
(select a.*
 from article a
 order by a.price asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select a.*
 from article a
 order by a.price desc
 limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select top 1 ArtNr as ART,Price price from XCPCONC order by Price asc) as a

union all

select * from (select top 1 ArtNr as ART,Price price from XCPCONC order by Price desc) as d

Comment: TOP is not supported by MySql.